# Async processing on UI bound dependency properties

Tags: wpf, asynchronous, task, dependency-properties, dispatcher

I'm working on a WPF application which has its business logic handled by a class library (without MVVM). Most properties of the business logic are dependency properties, which allows for an easy data binding to the WPF UI.

I have a datagrid that displays a collection of items (dependency property of the class):`ObservableCollection<ItemEntry> EntryCollection`.

The goal is to asynchronously call the  `ItemEntryUpdateAnalyzer.Analyze(ItemTemplate, Company, entry)` static method for every item in the EntryCollection as the processing takes a few seconds.

I started by doing the following :

```
    private async void AnalyzeButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        List<Task> tasks = EntryCollection.Select(entry => Task.Run(() => AnalyzeItemEntries())).ToList();
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    }

    private void AnalyzeItemEntries()
    {
        Log.Debug("Begin");
        Thread.Sleep(500);
        Log.Debug("End");
    }
```

That worked just fine, but adding the processing method throws an System.InvalidOperationException on a dependancy property of the ItemTemplate

```
    private void AnalyzeItemEntries(ItemEntry entry)
    {
        Log.Debug("Begin");
        ItemEntryUpdateAnalyzer.Analyze(ItemTemplate, Company, entry); //InvalidOperationException
        Log.Debug("End");
    }
```

This is due to the fact that the arguments of the Analyze method belong the the main UI thread. So I tried using the dispatcher to give the right context by doing the following :

```
    private void AnalyzeItemEntries(ItemEntry entry)
    {
        Log.Debug("Begin");
        /*tried with InvokeAsync as well*/
        Dispatcher?.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
        {
            ItemEntryUpdateAnalyzer.Analyze(ItemTemplate, Company, entry);
        }));
        Log.Debug("End");
    }
```

But that doesn't really helps as this locks the main thread. The problem is that the arguments are bound the the UI by dependency properties, normal properties don't seem to throw the exception.

**EDIT:**

I tried to deep copy the ItemTemplate and ItemEntry to local variables using the DeepCloner NuGet (https://github.com/force-net/DeepCloner) :

```
    private async void AnalyzeButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Log.Debug($"==== Main thread ID {Thread.CurrentThread} ===");

        ItemTemplate localTemplate = ItemTemplate.DeepClone();
        ObservableCollection<ItemEntry> localEntryCollection = EntryCollection.DeepClone();
        foreach (ItemEntry entry in localEntryCollection)
        {
            await Task.Run(() => AnalyzeItemEntries(localTemplate, entry));
        }
    }

    private void AnalyzeItemEntries(ItemTemplate template, ItemEntry entry)
    {
        Log.Debug($"Begin {entry.ItemCode}");
        ItemEntryUpdateAnalyzer.Analyze(template, Company, entry);
        Log.Debug($"End {entry.ItemCode}");
    }
```

I'm still getting the same error. The problem seems to be only related to dependency properties as accessing `entry.ItemCode` (standard property) works and accessing `entry.Action` does not.

Comment: An exception has a stack trace, check it out to get more details on where/what for the error happens.

Comment: This isn't the answer, but does the same happen when you add `.ConfigureAwait( false );` to the `WhenAll` just out of curiosity?

Comment: I also tried to add ```.ConfigureAwait(false)```, unfortunately it didn't work.

Comment: @XAMIMAX : The UI element is not passed in the ```Analyze``` method. The UI controls are bound to Dependency properties that are located in the ```ItemTemplate``` and ```ItemEntry``` objects.  Is that  considered bad design ?

Comment: How does the implementation of ItemTemplate looks like then and item entry looks like? If those are your models/viewmodels then you would have no need for DPs? The usual INPC should suffice. Do you use previous values of those props? Thats why you would use a DP on a model. Or do you bind values in xaml to your models?

Comment: @XAMIMAX : Let's say I have a window called window1. window 1 contains a dependency property of the ItemTemplate object. All the properties of the item template are also dependency properties. That allows me to bind ui elements to attributes of the ItemTemplate.

Comment: What you are describing is standard Binding in WPF, your VM doesn't have DPs on it, just standard .NET props. If you use plain props would that stop your bindings from working? If I were to guess, I think that ItemTemplate controls how the UI, looks and feel, therefore holds some sort of UI elements? Like brushes or Thickness? That also is prone to shortcuts of not using converters for property Bindings. Am I correct?

Comment: ItemTemplate and ItemEntry only hold business data, not UI objects. I could use plain props, but I would have to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged interface to let my UI update dynamically when the properties are changed. Instead of doing that, I inherited my business objects from DependencyObject and use dependency properties.

Comment: Ah, I see. When you did that then you had to write SetValue(ref prop); and (objectType)GetValue(); for getters and setters. With INPC you would only add OnPropertyChanged(); to a full property. A lot less coding and a lot more readable. And to ease implementation of INPC use a base class call it `ObservableObject` then inherit from it so you have the functionality. use `[CallerMemberName]` for onPorpertyChanged so you don't have to specify which property has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Dependency properties are a UI-level object. Background threads (including those used by `Task.Run`) cannot directly access UI objects.

One way around this is to copy the UI properties into local variables and pass those variables to the background thread, something like this:

```
private async void AnalyzeButton_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  var itemTemplate = ItemTemplate;
  var company = Company;
  List<Task> tasks = EntryCollection.Select(entry => Task.Run(() => AnalyzeItemEntries(itemTemplate, company, entry))).ToList();
  await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
}
```

Depending on the shape of `ItemTemplate` / `Company` / `Entry`, you may need to make these into "deep" copies. Also, depending on the behavior of `AnalyzeItemEntries`, you may need to change that method to return values rather than updating objects as side effects.

Comment: I thought about passing copies of the objects to the tasks, then returning them afterwards, the problem is that I can't clone the objects as they are not serializable. The ItemTemplate has a ```ToJSON()``` that was manually implemented, so I guess that I could convert it to and from JSON to get a copy.

I'm more concerned about the Company object which comes from an API (DIAPI for SAP)

Comment: @matthiasboularot: Only clone them if you need to (i.e., if the objects have thread affinity).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to everyone for your help, The Ideal solution would be to use regular properties instead of dependency properties, but I can't do that in my application.

I've set the `DispatcherPriority` to `ApplicationIdle`. that gives back some responsiveness to the UI.

```
            await Dispatcher?.InvokeAsync(() =>
            {
                ItemEntryUpdateAnalyzer.Analyze(ItemTemplate, Company, entry);

            },
            DispatcherPriority.ApplicationIdle);
```